# catalogue.RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy.copy_from_base_model.v1' in function registry 'callbacks'

Tags: named-entity-recognition, spacy-3

I'm a  Spacy's new user and I'm trying to run this [ner_demo_update project](https://github.com/explosion/projects/tree/v3/pipelines/ner_demo_update) and I got this error :
*catalogue.RegistryError: [E893] Could not find function 'spacy.copy_from_base_model.v1' in function registry 'callbacks'. If you're using a custom function, make sure the code is available. If the function is provided by a third-party package, e.g. spacy-transformers, make sure the package is installed in your environment.*
I'll like to know if someone has face the same  issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`copy_from_base_model.v1` is a new function, introduced in spaCy v3.0.6. Are you perhaps running an older version of spaCy? If so, can you try updating it? This will likely resolve your error.

See also: https://github.com/explosion/spaCy/discussions/7985